# Which is best solution for supply chain application fabric or sawtooth?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am little confused bw fabric and sawtooth for supply chain application development from documentation it appears that sawtooth is best for supply chain but all the validator node keeps the copy of the distributed ledger there is no concept of channels and private data.

Answer (score 3):

Sawtooth has an open source solution for supply chain.

Fabric Channels may solve your use case. It doesn't scale if you need several channels. You can also have multiple blockchains with Sawtooth, which is essentially what a channel is anyway.

The blockchain concept is that all data is transaparent and viewable and auditable by everyone. That doesn't always work in some use cases and is an active research area. Encrypting payload data and storing some data off-chain are some solutions.

Comment: Hello Dan, I have few concerns over choosing sawtooth.

 Manually sign each batch and transactions.
Rely on event and transaction recipts events in order to confirm that batches have been submitted.
In order to support rich queries we have to maintain offchain copy of the ledger.

Don't you think its extra work as compared to fabric where these can be handled without any extra effort by using couchdb and inbuild fabric features.